# What changes to the code do I need to do when publishing on Amazon app store?

Tags: amazon-appstore

I have an app on GooglePlay and would like to publish on Amazon app store.

Is there anything I need to change in my code?

Most likely, the licence check from Google library has to be removed. Right?

Is there anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't think I need to answer this  but my app just completed a successful review today. And I did not make any changes in my app. I believe if you are using Billing, Advertisements, Maps and any feature that has an implementation by Amazon must be changed.

Comment: I thought in particular about copy protection.